# Explanation of return code from SHFileOperation()

Tags: winapi, return-value, shfileoperation

Is there a reason `SHFileOperation()` returns `32`?

My scenario is:

- My current path is `c:\foo\bar`.
- My file is in `c:\foo`
- That file is going to the Recycle Bin.

This code is not listed as possible return value in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shfileoperationa#return-value), and I don't know where to find the cause.

I am trying it on Windows 7 64-bit with MSVC 2010 Professional.

Could someone please explain where I can find the returned values documentation or some explanation for a reason of that failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHFileOperation` returns errors, which match to `Winerror.h` error values.

`32` is defined as `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`, meaning "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." This means that another process accesses the file you want to change by calling `SHFileOperation`.

You might as well use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)'s find-feature to find out, which process accesses the file you want to change.

Comment: thank you. Any idea on how to check it?Problem is I just created the file and I see it exists in the File Explorer, but I can't trash it, because of this error. I'm doing a test suite.

Comment: You can use Process Explorer's Find Handle or DLL functionality in order to find out what process accesses your file.

Comment: are those part of MSVC install or external apps?

Comment: Process Explorer belongs to Microsoft's Windows Sysinternals.

Answer (score 0):

From my testing (so verify yourself)

`32` = File in use or perhaps file locked/protected.
(Created an excel wkbk, opened, typed text, tried to delete)

`2` = not found

`0` = no issues

`4`, `8`, `16` return codes seem likely

Comment: I just found this:         https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-?redirectedfrom=MSDN